# Creating a P5.js 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to port my working processing sketch to p5.js so I can use it online. But I'm running into a problem when trying to set the values in a 2 dimensional array. I think I'm following the correct syntax shown in the 2d array section of the API, but am getting an uncaught type error that says "cannot set property 0 of undefined".

The sketch is pretty simple, I'm just trying to read from a CSV and store the data in a 2D array:

```
var cols = 8;
var rows = 8;
var month = 1;
var values = [];
var table;

function preload(){
    table = loadTable("1988.csv", "csv");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    var totalRows = table.getRowCount();

    for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            values[c]=[];
            for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                values[r+m*rows][c] = table.getNum(m*rows*cols + c*rows + r, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: values is initialised as a 1D at the top perhaps. Can you try ```var values = new Array(12);``` ?

Comment: Thanks for responding, George. In regular processing, 2d arrays have to be defined as such when they are initialized, but it looks the documentation on P5.js doesn't do that: http://p5js.org/learn/examples/Arrays_Array_2D.php

Comment: notice this line in the documentation snippet: ```distances[x] = []; // create nested array```

Comment: @george I thought I allocated the array with `values[c] = [];` in line 17. Also, here's the setup from my original processing sketch  which hopefully makes things more clear.   `int cols = 8;  

int [][] values;  
void setup() {  
  size(800, 800);  
  Table table = loadTable("1988.csv");  
  int totalRows = table.getRowCount();  
  values = new int [totalRows][cols];  
  for (int m = 0; m < months; m++) {  
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {  
      for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) { 
        values[r+m*rows][c] = table.getInt(m*rows*cols + c*rows + r, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating the array before setting array access values to `undefined` objects:

```
var cols = 8;
var rows = 8;
var month = 1;
var months = 12;
var values = new Array(months);
var table;

function preload(){
    table = loadTable("1988.csv", "csv");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < months; i++) values[i] = [];//initialize 2nd dimension of the array as well, not just the 1st
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    var totalRows = table.getRowCount();

    for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            values[c]=[];
            for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                values[r+m*rows][c] = table.getNum(m*rows*cols + c*rows + r, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```